# how to apply frequency-dependent attenuation to a signal

Tags: signal, frequency, signal-processing, frequency-measurement, attenuation

Let's suppose a signal like this:
[image: signal in Time domain]

the frequency domain plot of such a signal is:

[image: Frequency domain plot of the signal]

Now, What I intend to do is to apply a frequency-dependent correction to the signal.
For example, the attenuation rate at 40 MHz is 2.2dB while at 50 MHz it is 2.5 dB.
Is it alright if I apply the correction to the magnitude value in each desired frequency in the frequency domain and then use the inverse Fourier to achieve the modified time-domain plot of the signal?

Comment: Probably not.  It won't work as well as you'd hope.  It'll do something, but won't work as well as a normal filter.

Comment: Your questiion is essentially the *basic* question in the subject of "filter design."  There is substantial subject matter toward that end.  Having said that, the answer to your question is "yes" -- if you constructed a time-domain filter whose reponse was the (time-domain) inverse of the desired Fourier response of your desired filter -- yes, your filter would exactly achieve your specifications.  The big question is larger: Are my requirements *truly* what I need?  What about in-band and out-of-band behaviors?  Do I care about imperfections (i.e. Chebyshev vs Butterworth vs anything else?)..

Comment: XY problem - explain what you want to happen and not how you think it might be achieved.

Comment: @Atomique Thanks for the explanation.

Comment: @andy-aka as I said: What I intend to do is to apply a frequency-dependent correction to a time-domain signal.

Comment: @FernandoSanz what Andy asks is "apply that... for which purpose?", because that enables us to understand why something might or might not work for you.

Comment: @Marcus Müller Let's say this signal is recorded after transferring into a long coaxial cable. What I want to know is the amplitude of the signal before the transmission begins.

Comment: Yeah, then you're planning to do something that you shouldn't be doing; for details see: https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/6220/why-is-it-a-bad-idea-to-filter-by-zeroing-out-fft-bins (zeroing out is the same as mulitplying with a factor, just that the factor is 0)